# How to find the summation of the following series? .

Tags: homogeneous-equation

If $$S=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i2^{i}},$$ Then how can I find the summation of the above series up to $n^{th}$ terms? I can't solve this question because I don't know whether this summation is a series expansion of any function or not. I know the series expansions of $\cos(x)$, $\sin(x)$, $\tan(x)$, $e^{x}$, $\tan^{-1}x$, $\ln(1+x)$, $\ln(1-x)$, etc. But I am confused that the above summation is the series expansion of which function. Please help me out.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Well $-\ln(1-x)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{x^j}{j}$ when $\lvert x\rvert<1$, so $\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{1}{j2^j}=-\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)=\ln(2)$ if that helps

Comment: Hint: first do the formula for $\sum_{i=1}^n x^i$ when $|x|<1$.  Then integrate that result with respect to $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us define a function for $|x| < 1$ and $n \in \mathcal{N}$,
$$S(x,n) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x^i}{i}$$

Differentiating this function w.r.t $x$,
$$\frac{d}{dx} S(x,n) = \sum_{i=1}^n x^{i-1} = \frac{1-x^n}{1-x}$$

Integrating this function from $0$ t0 $x$,
$$S(x,n) = \int_{u=0}^x \frac{1-u^n}{1-u} du$$

Your requirement is the value $S(\frac{1}{2}, n)$